# Number of spanning arborescences with a specific root in a directed graph

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees, directed-graphs

I am wondering how to calculate the number of spanning arborescences in a directed graph when a root is specified. For example:

[image]

where there are 5 spanning arborescences. Note that there is an edge from `b2` to `b3` and one from `b3` to `b2`.

Angela Pretorius mentioned a method in [Number of Spanning Arborescences, Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95360/number-of-spanning-arborescences#comment224882_95360), but there is no euclidean circuit in this example. It seems that he/she is referring to [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem#Kirchhoff%27s_theorem_for_directed_multigraphs) can be used:

> Kirchhoff's theorem can be modified to count the number of oriented spanning trees in directed multigraphs. The matrix Q is constructed as follows:
>
> The entry i, j for distinct i and j equals −m, where m is the number of edges from i to j;
> The entry i, i equals the indegree of i minus the number of loops at i.
>
> The number of oriented spanning trees rooted at a vertex i is the determinant of the matrix gotten by removing the i-th row and column of Q.